# Как заставить объект двигаться в определенном направлении(автоматически) в Unity 2018

Tags: c#, unity3d

Дело в том, как заставить обьект фоновые обьекты двигаться в определенном направлении в Unity 2018?

Comment: Какие способы двигать обьекты ты уже пробовал и чем это закончилось?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите получить, дополните вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

JonAlan перетащите этот Script в объект:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 4f;
    // С какой скоростью должен двигаться объект

    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        // Vector3.в какое направление двигаться объекту
    }
}
```

если появятся вопросы насчёт скрипта задавайте!